# Chromium won't play any YouTube videos; Firefox plays them

Tags: debian, video, streaming, youtube, devuan

I'm using Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster), freshly installed.

I can play YouTube videos fine using Firefox, but if I try them in Chromium, it keeps showing the loading animation (the circle with the gradient repeating itself), and at some point adds "if playback doesn't begin shortly, please restart your device".

Restarting does not work. The comment sections also won't load. On the other hand, many/most/all non-YouTube videos load fine, e.g., Vimeo.

I'm not using any manually-installed software.

What could be the cause? 
How can I fix/work around this issue?

Comment: Have you verified Flash content is enabled in Chromium? Chromium version 76 has Flash disabled by default  https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap Also see https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-chromium.html

Comment: @K7AAY: I've tried following the instructions at your second link, sort of. I've manually installed the plugin as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391472/34868) (first option); then I restarted chromium. But about:plugins gives me nothing.

Comment: That means that some addons are causing this, that concerns youtube comments as well try to disable 3rd parties addons and reload the browser it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have the necessary codecs.

I always install mpv, which has a lot of common codecs as dependencies.

So, my first guess is to:

```
sudo apt-get install mpv
```

Comment: `mpv is already the newest version (0.29.1-1).`  <- Also, that should probably make Firefox fail to play them as well.

Comment: a movie player has nothing to do with a youtube in chrome. just specify the codec you think is responsible if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that it was the uMatrix-plugin which inhibited youtube from loading videos.

It seems that Google had changes the hostnames so I had to re-add exception to uMatrix.